# Select both options if it's me, select only one if it's other users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table NOTES in MySql, and in it is column Draft. Draft can be 0 or 1, with 1 meaning note is still a draft.

Each row is one note, and each row has one user as note creator.

How can I select rows, within one query, from table NOTES from all users, but exclude notes that are other users' drafts, while including my drafts? In other words, how can I select notes with Draft set to 0 for all users except me, and Draft set to either 0 or 1 for me?

(By the way, table NOTES has column UserId, and there's also table USERS, with each user having Id. And, I know my Id.)

I don't have any meaningful query, but the beginning is, arguably:

SELECT * FROM notes, users WHERE... eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for simple logic:

```
select n.*
from notes n
where draft = 0 or userid = $userid ;
```

That is, select all notes that are not drafts as well as all notes from the specified user.